# React/React Native Experience Point Counter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, counter, points

I am trying to make an experience point counter for a project I am working on.  I want it to increase by 15 each time the user reaches the "Quiz Completion" page that I have and display the number on the profile page.  But I've only seen tutorials on how to make counters with a manual button to increment and decrement.

I'm a beginner with React so I was wondering if anyone can explain how to make one like I described?  Examples would be great too!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React Functional Components (RFC), you can use from useEffect hook that you should import from React and use from empty dependency to run your code once (when a user opens this screen).
You can write your codes (to increase the score) in the callback of useEffect like this:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function QuizCompletion() {

  useEffect(() => {
    // Your code for increase your score state here
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that out!  But how would I get it to display on the profile page?  Also what is the import of styles.css for?

Comment: I dont believe increasing experience point inside`useEffect` is a good idea. React calls `useEffect` callbacks twice in development mode. You should increase the points before navigating to the completion page.

Comment: Also server should calculates the points and returns it to the user. You should read the points from the server response and display it.

Comment: Do you send the quiz data to a server? Or is it just stored in your user's browser?

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should NOT use `useEffect`. Right before navigating to 'Quiz Completion' page you probably send some data to server. If the request is successful, you should add to experience point counter in its callback.

Comment: I'm not using a server for this project unfortunately..  Is there another way to implement this method to calculate and display the points?

Comment: You can store the points in `localSorage`. To display the points you need to read the points from `localStorage`. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: Okay, I will check into this!